# Visio 2016 How to prevent Relationship lines to unglue from entities?

Tags: visio

I have a simple Entity-diagram (crows foot) in Visio 2016. When I draw relationships between the entities, they can be glued to the entity, an attribute or a connection point. This is all good, but very often when I move an entity around on the page, the endpoints of the Relationship, that was attached to the entity, will suddenly become unglued (hanging loose without any connection).

Is there any way to keep them hanging on to the entity?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, don't move the connectors, only the entities themselves.

Comment: That is what I do, but when I do that the connectors "disengages" from the entity that is not moved.

Comment: Either the connectors were not properly glued (you can make a connector snap to a point without actually gluing it), or you really selected not only the shape, but also the connector. Can't imagine another scenario.